# zpool won't import after crash while resilvering

Tags: linux, ubuntu, zfs, zfsonlinux

With triple-mirrored vdevs, I'm really not sure why I can't re-import anyway.  There was also a read cache vdev, but that is no longer connected, though that doesn't seem to be the issue.  I've all but given up, but maybe someone else can point me in a new direction.

Here's what I see:

```
# zpool import -o ro -f -m
   pool: tank
     id: 15181238712954073451
  state: UNAVAIL
 status: One or more devices were being resilvered.
 action: The pool cannot be imported due to damaged devices or data.
 config:

    tank                      UNAVAIL  missing device
      mirror-0                ONLINE
        powervault-16f4fc     ONLINE
        powervault-16f268     ONLINE
        powervault-b8e400     ONLINE
      mirror-1                ONLINE
        powervault-b89ddc     ONLINE
        powervault-b90178     ONLINE
        powervault-16f134     ONLINE
      mirror-2                ONLINE
        powervault-b91060     ONLINE
        powervault-b92ad8     ONLINE
        powervault-d9de69     ONLINE
      mirror-3                ONLINE
        powervault-1703ec     ONLINE
        powervault-b8d670     ONLINE
        powervault-b90144     ONLINE
      mirror-4                ONLINE
        powervault-489817     ONLINE
        powervault-b915b0     ONLINE
        powervault-b73838     ONLINE
      mirror-5                ONLINE
        powervault-b9114c     ONLINE
        powervault-b92b30     ONLINE
        powervault-16cbd0     ONLINE
      mirror-6                DEGRADED
        powervault-b90f70     ONLINE
        powervault-b915c8     ONLINE
        11183873526684940444  UNAVAIL
      mirror-7                ONLINE
        powervault-b92050     ONLINE
        powervault-b90d4c     ONLINE
        powervault-b3ec0c     ONLINE
      mirror-8                ONLINE
        powervault-170a68     ONLINE
        powervault-16f00c     ONLINE
        powervault-b916a0     ONLINE
      mirror-9                ONLINE
        powervault-1700c4     ONLINE
        powervault-b8fa5c     ONLINE
        powervault-b91ad4     ONLINE
      mirror-10               DEGRADED
        12935469030838970131  UNAVAIL
        powervault-b915d0     ONLINE
        powervault-b90f04     ONLINE
```

Comment: The UNAVAIL devices really are hard fails now, so they're not coming back.

Comment: Sorry I didn't include versions...

Ubuntu originally Bionic, now Focal.
zfs originally 0.7.5, now 0.8.3

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Please [take the tour](https://superuser.com/tour) to learn how Super User works. Read [how to ask](https://superuser.com/questions/how-to-ask) to improve the quality of your question. Then take a look to [the help center](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic) to see if some _on-topic questions_ are already asked.